# How to grab only first occurrence of an element with same text

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have written a jQuery code which displays only the first occurrence of a heading tag with same text.

### Below is the jQuery code:

```
$("h1").each(function(){
   $("h1:contains('"+$(this).text()+"')").first().css('display','block');
});
```

### Current HTML in the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BKbM5/):

```
<h1>heading1</h1>
<p>hello</p>
<h1>heading1</h1>
<p>hello</p>
<h1>heading2</h1>
<p>hello</p>
<h1>heading2</h1>
<p>hello</p>
<h1>heading1</h1>
<p>hello</p>
<h1>heading3</h1>
<p>hello</p>
<h1>heading3</h1>
<p>hello</p>
```

### CSS for hiding all `h1`s in the beginning:

```
h1{
    display:none;
}
```

---

The current `.each()` loop will *iterate 7 times* even if there is need for only *3 iterations* if I can get the first occurrence of `<h1>` tags with same text , in the current fiddle :- **`<h1>heading1</h1>` , `<h1>heading2</h1>` , `<h1>heading3</h1>`** .

I can write a condition in which it check the *previous `h1` text* with *current `h1` text* if the same text headings are one after another.But you can see in the HTML that the third **`<h1>heading1</h1>`** is appearing after **`<h1>heading2</h1>`** in which case the condition wont work.

***So is there a way that I can get the same output with exact number of iterations as needed and more performance effective code than the current one?***

Comment: if you know the positions, you can use css. [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/BKbM5/6/)

Comment: @Mr_Green thanks for the help but I know `:nth-child()` and if I actually know the position I will surely use `:nth-child()` .But here I am asking for random positions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can optimize it by neglecting the visible ones,

```
$("h1").each(function(){
   if($(this).is(':visible')) { return; }
   $("h1:contains('"+$(this).text()+"')").first().css('display','block');
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BKbM5/1/)

Updated version,

```
$("h1").each(function (i) {
    if ($(this).data('validated') === '1') {
        return;
    }
    $("h1:contains('" + $(this).text() + "')").data('validated','1').first().show();
});
```

### [DEMO I](http://jsfiddle.net/da3Tf/3/)

And you can see the updated performance test over [here](http://jsperf.com/skipping)

Comment: no... still the loop is executed 7 times http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/da3Tf/2/ - the return is not working

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yes of course, the loop will execute 7 times but it will act like a `continue` statement so we can skip the dom traversal for the unnecessary iterations.. Please see the performance test to ensure that.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy no.. if you add a console logging after the if  as I gave it is printing 7 times

Comment: Ok i am testing all solutions and will accept an answer which is best

Comment: Surprisigly when tested my actual code is taking lesser time : **1)** my : http://jsfiddle.net/BKbM5/3/ **2)** Raj : http://jsfiddle.net/da3Tf/6/ **3)** Arun : http://jsfiddle.net/da3Tf/7/ .So is the actual really taking less time?

Comment: Ok so seeing http://jsperf.com/so-22854835-1 I do understand this is a good solution and I surely will accept you answer based on ops/sec .But just answer this last question : Should i consider ops/sec or the time taken for completion?

Comment: When I tested it , on increasing HTML code the execution time of original jQuery code increases at a rate more than yours.So thanks for the answer @RajaprabhuAravindasamy

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var $h1s = $("h1"),
    $cp = $h1s,
    $tmp;

for (var i = 0; i < $h1s.length; i++) {
    $tmp = $h1s.filter(":contains('" + $h1s.eq(i).text() + "')");
    $tmp.first().show();
    $cp = $cp.not($tmp.first())
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/da3Tf/)

In each iteration we remove all the ignored elements from the source array.

Comment: Well this is showing exact count but just to know will it take less time than what i posted?

Comment: Surprisigly when tested my actual code is taking lesser time : **1)** my : http://jsfiddle.net/BKbM5/3/ **2)** Raj : http://jsfiddle.net/da3Tf/6/ **3)** Arun : http://jsfiddle.net/da3Tf/7/ .So is the actual really taking less time?

Comment: So should i consider ops/sec or the time taken for completion?

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this:

```
$("h1").each(function(){
   return $("h1:contains('"+$(this).text()+"')").first();
}).css('display','block');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method to check if the element is visible on-screen would be:

```
$("h1").each(function(){
   if(($(this).css("visibility") != "hidden")) {
       $("h1:contains('"+$(this).text()+"')").first().css('display','block');
   }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9UBB3/)